# Why can I only access 3gb of RAM with 8 installed on a 64-bit system?

Tags: ram

Why can I only access 3gb of RAM with 8 installed on 64 bit system?  My BIOS recognizes all 8 gb installed in the system.  I thought by installing 64-bit Ubuntu would take advantage of the higher RAM installed.

I am running an Intel Core i3 540 
Can I access this 8 gb somehow?
Thanks in advance.

```
--memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 30
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous
          product: ModulePartNumber00
          vendor: Manufacturer00
          physical id: 0
          serial: SerNum00
          slot: DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous
          product: ModulePartNumber01
          vendor: Manufacturer01
          physical id: 1
          serial: SerNum01
          slot: DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
```

On the Ubuntu about page it shows 3.0 Gib instead of the 8 you see above.

[image: Screenshot of system info]

Comment: How do you know only 3gb of ram is being accessed?  Did you `sudo lshw -C memory` (list hardware class memory) and see only some there?  Does `free` and like commands show only part there?  If so why not provide your proof & details so we can help?  (please edit your questions and add additional info there, don't provide it in comments which have little formatting & editing options)

Comment: Probably related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier

Comment: Did you recently upgrade your RAM? If so, you went from what to what? Did you check what the maximum RAM is supported in your computer? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema  No I recently made a dual boot sytem giving linux its own physical hard drive to install 64 bit.

Comment: Did you check what the maximum RAM is supported in your computer? Some older laptops may have only supported 4G RAM max, even if a 8G stick got installed.

Comment: Yes @heynnema I have checked the system and I am running the maximum amount of ram 8 gib

Comment: Your RAM sticks may need to be reseated in their sockets. Do that and see if it helps. You may also have a bad RAM, or motherboard... jury is still out. If not, boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see what it says about RAM. Report back.

Comment: When you reboot, run memtest86+ from the options list if it's available.  Let the test run fully (will take time), and let us know if it gives any errors.

Comment: @heynnema still no joy.  No errors found with memtest86+

Comment: I have reseated and even swapped slots with them.  Still can not get 8 gb here...

Comment: I can't remember how to post pics in these threads.  Anyway, after trying all of the above the hardware check shows 2 banks of 4 gb each.

Comment: The system screen shows the same as before- 3gb

Comment: @DavidSmith lets eliminate a defective RAM slot. Remove 1 RAM stick. That should show up as 4G when the system is booted. If it doesn't boot, the OTHER RAM slot is defective. If it DOES show up as 4G, return the 1st RAM stick to its ORIGINAL slot, and remove the 2nd RAM stick. If it boots, it should also say 4G. If it does not boot, the other RAM slot is defective. Report back to "@heynnema"

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the help.  I have tried your suggestion and each slot is working correctly and each stick of ram shows 4 gb. Just wonder if there is a pae workaround in linux.  I know it should just show by itself without that kind of help.. Still unhappy.  Windows 32 bit obviously shows 8gb installed with only  3.1 usable which is normal for that version of windows.  But this copy of linux is 64 bit. My processor is 64 bit. Motherboad is ok.  Just dont know why I cant use all of the ram I bought.  Its all very new.

Comment: @DavidSmith If you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB you have the same problem, yes? Sorry, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @DavidSmith last thought... in your BIOS, did you allocate ~4G to an internal video card?

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for all the suggestions.  I did boot the dvd live prior to installing and it would only show 3gb available.  In the bios I have not allocated anything.  I have Intel hd graphics onboard w/ 128mb ram. I havent changed it.  In Windows I am told that with the Intel HD Graphics onboard you can't breach the 3gb limit.  Not sure if thats true but if it is, could that be the issue here?  Anyway,  Thank you all for the suggestions.  I was hoping to use all of the new ram I put in.  May just as well remove one stick and put it away. :(  Not really what I want thought...